# Summarise Country Active/Inactive

Tags: sql-server, database

I have this data that I have been trying to achieve and wrote here on SQL Server 2017: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c457bc/109

```
CREATE TABLE customer
    ([CustomerID] int, [State] varchar(34), [ContactName] varchar(18), [Address] varchar(29), [City] varchar(12), [PostalCode] varchar(8), [Country] varchar(9))
;
    
INSERT INTO customer
    ([CustomerID], [State], [ContactName], [Address], [City], [PostalCode], [Country])
VALUES
    (1, 'I', 'Maria Anders', 'Obere Str. 57', 'Berlin', '12209', 'Germany'),
    (2, 'A', 'Ana Trujillo', 'Avda. de la Constitución 2222', 'C', '05021', 'Mexico'),
    (3, 'I', 'Antonio Moreno', 'Mataderos 2312', 'B', '05023', 'Mexico'),
    (4, 'I', 'Thomas Hardy', '120 Hanover Sq.', 'London', 'WA1 1DP', 'UK'),
    (5, 'I', 'Christina Berglund', 'Berguvsvägen 8', 'Luleå', 'S-958 22', 'Sweden'),
    (6, 'I', 'Hanna Moos', 'Forsterstr. 57', 'Mannheim', '68306', 'Germany'),
    (7, 'A', 'Frédérique Citeaux', '24, place Kléber', 'Strasbourg', '67000', 'France'),
    (8, 'A', 'Martín Sommer', 'C/ Araquil, 67', 'Madrid', '28023', 'France'),
    (9, 'A', 'Laurence Lebihans', '12, rue des Bouchers', 'Marseille', '13008', 'France'),
    (10, 'A', 'Elizabeth Lincoln', '23 Tsawassen Blvd.', 'Tsawassen', 'T2F 8M4', 'Canada'),
    (11, 'I', 'Victoria Ashworth', 'Fauntleroy Circus', 'London', 'EC2 5NT', 'UK'),
    (12, 'A', 'Francisco Chang', 'Sierras de Granada 9993', 'A', '05022', 'Mexico')
```

I want to get the data in this format

[image: Data format needed]

```
Germany | I
UK      | I
Mexico  | A
France  | A
Sweden  | I
Canada  | A
```

Basically, if the state of the country is A (active) or I (inactive), the state should show A, if the state is all A, then it should show A, if its all Is, only then it should show I.

The above is a small data set, but I am working on a bigger data set.

Please help.

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including all relevant data directly here, rather than in some external link (which could break over time).

Comment: how do i add a table ?

Comment: ^^ As I have done for you - if you click edit you can see how its done.

Comment: Thank you Dale, will follow it for my future posts, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the fiddle

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cbf46/1)

```
SELECT
DISTINCT COUNTRY,
CASE
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY AND STATE='A')<=0 THEN 'I' 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY AND STATE='I')<=0 THEN 'A'
ELSE 'A'
END AS STATE
FROM 
CUSTOMER C
```

What I did, is, get all `COUNTRY` as unique with `DISTINCT` and then count values with 'A' or 'I'. If value is ZERO, then set opposite STATE as answer and so on. Otherwise set `A`.